# How to add title or tag to UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiactivityindicatorview

I am supposed to render a pdf book in ipad and navigate through the pages. In between the navigation i am displaying a UIActivityIndicatorView to indicate that the page is still loading.... I am able to do this without any trouble. But, is there a way in which i can have a tag or label or name along with(or beside) that UIActivityIndicator.... 
Please answer this.. Eagerly waiting for ur inputs... 
Thanks and Regards.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try MBProgressHUD, it looks like Apple's official indicator

Comment: i have checked the iOS API for MBProgressHUD, but there is no trace of it anywhere....??? it is also not available for MAC OSX or Safari....

Comment: @A for Alpha: Sorry but I only used it for my iOS app. I've no experience in Mac OS development.

Comment: thanku so much diwup..infact im new to this platform and am not sure whether that was from apple or not... anyway thankyou so much for ur help and keep helping me with your answers.....